# Изображение по центру кнопки android

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Есть кнопка, на которой по центру должно быть изображение + текст, не могу понять как переместить изображение на центр.
Код кнопки:

```
<Button
                        android:id="@+id/disco"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#6CC51D"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_proc"
                        android:onClick="opnDisc"
                        android:text="Товари зі знижкою"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Кнопка выглядит так:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKPg4.png

А должна так
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezs6H.png

Comment: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_proc"` - почему `Left`?

Comment: @DrMcSheen обычный android:drawable не отображает вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать при помощь `MaterialButton`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#6CC51D"
            android:text="Товари зі знижкою"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:icon="@drawable/info_icon"
            app:iconGravity="textStart" />
```

по итогу будет так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ключевое здесь это:

```
app:icon="@drawable/info_icon"
app:iconGravity="textStart"
```